# Airflow Scheduler issue

Tags: sqlalchemy, virtualenv, airflow-scheduler

I am getting error whenever executing the airflow scheduler

> sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) disk I/O error
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Comment: same problem on windows10 wsl